# How do I revalidate a server component or page using an onClick event handler while using the app directory in NextJs v13.2

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I know I can set `revalidate: 5` to make it revalidate every 5 seconds,

But I want to trigger the revalidation using an onClick event handler on the frontend ui react component.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to revalidate every 5 seconds on `serverSide`. Just change the logic.

If you force it to `"revalidate on server-side"` it will re-render your page.

If you like to revalidate data on your page (or component), you need to use [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/#overview) library.

Follow this steps:

1. Create your page or component (I think you already did it)
2. Create or take API route.
3. Use useSWR library with `revalidate` of 5 seconds.

Here is an example:

```
import useSWR from "swr";

const fetcher = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log("data refreshed")
  return data;
};

const Example = () => {
  const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR(
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/new.json",
    fetcher,
    {
      refreshInterval: 5000
    }
  );

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    mutate();
    console.log("data refreshed manually");
  };

  if (error) return <div>Error fetching data</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Posts from r/funny</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.data.children.map((post) => (
          <li key={post.data.id}>
            <a href={`https://www.reddit.com${post.data.permalink}`}>
              {post.data.title}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleRefresh}>Refresh Data</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

*P.S. you can't "trigger onClick" without the user clicking the button, but in my example useSWR library will do it for you.*